# opening old external encrypted partition: error

Tags: luks, device-mapper, disk-encryption

I have an encrypted hard disk with luks encryption. When I try to open it via:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 backup
```

It prompts me for a password, but then errors out on me:

> device-mapper: reload ioctl on  failed: No such file or directory

My device still has header information, though:

```
LUKS header information for /dev/sdc1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    cbc-essiv:sha256
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
...
```

I'm just making up the word `backup`. Do I need to register it somehow? Is my data recoverable?